# no matching function call error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

I'm trying to overload my << operator, but I want to use a helper function because I'm working with a tree, and that way my helper fn. can be recursive. But when I try to call the helper from the operator function I'm getting this no matching function call error.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Polynomial &rhs)
{
    Polynomial::Node *p = rhs.root;
    rhs.printPoly(p, out);
    return out;
}


void Polynomial::printPoly(Node* p, std::ostream &out)
{
    if(p == nullptr)
        return;
    printPoly(p->left, out);
    out << p->item->coeff() << "x^" << p->item->x();
    printPoly(p->right, out);
}
```

and in the .h file

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Polynomial& rhs);
```

Oh and here's the error:

`no matching function for call to 'Polynomial::printPoly(Polynomial::Node*&, std::ostream&) const`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `const` to the end of your function declaration:

```
void Polynomial::printPoly(Node* p, std::ostream &out) const
{
    ...
}
```

This extra `const` tells the compiler that you won't be modifying the `Polynomial` object in the `printPoly` method.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and it was still yelling at me. I'll try again.

Comment: @ScubaSteve Sorry, I had a typo. Just updated my post... Try again.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks its working now. I like this solution better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just ditched the const in the declaration of Polynomial &rhs, and it seems happy.

Comment: You actually want that `const`, since you're not modifying the object in the function. Adding `const` qualifiers where appropriate helps avoid undesired side-effects and helps with compiler optimization.